# How to add "aliases" in many to many relationship in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many

I have many to many relationship between an actor and a theater_play.

How to add his `stage name` when making the connection? I have a table for the actor, a table for theater_play and a table for the connection of many to many call actor_theater_play where I connect the IDs.

My goal is to display `John Doe is know for his roles:` and then to list `Name of Play - Character Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theatre play relation on your `Actor` model, make sure you use the `->withPivot()` method to specify which pivot fields you want attached with the relation:

```
public function theaterPlays() {
    return hasMany(\App\TheaterPlay::class)->withPivot('stage_name');
}
```

You will then able able to access in your list (Laravel blade example):

```
@foreach($actor->theater_plays as $theater_play)
    {{ $theater_play->name . ' - ' . $theater_play->stage_name }}
@endforeach
```